# Is there a way to make align views from right to left as the development language is Arabic?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, arabic

I 'm working on arabic only app, I have designed all screen as from right to left approach and then tried to make the development language to arabic then every thing became left to right in runtime is there a way to solve this otherwise to flip every thing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do this using the following steps.

Click on the project (See below images) -> Edit scheme... -> Run -> Options -> application language (select arabic language)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I need to set ehe development language to Arabic, what you say will simulate as I set the phone language to which which is not what I mean